# cannot access value in companion object

Tags: scala, companion-object

I have a companion object which looks as follows:

```
case class ShowItemMessageStreamMock[A](item: A)

object ShowItemMessageStreamMock extends ShowItemMessageStream
{
    def addItemToMessageStream[A](view: A): Unit =
    {
        new ShowItemMessageStreamMock(view)
    }
}
```

and I have a assertion, which looks like this:

```
assert(ShowItemMessageStreamMock.item.nonEmpty)
```

( just pretend, that the addItemToMessageStream method ran and item has a value in it )

but when I hover over the item in the assertion, I get this error message:

> value item is not a member of object
> ShowItemMessageStreamMock

I thought, I can access all values of each companion?

So my question is, why can´t I acces this item value?

Comment: because in the addItemToMessageStream method i create a instance of the companion class and put the view into the companion class and therefor into the item... is this what you meant?

Comment: Why do you think there is `item` defined on companion object? What is `ShowItemMessageStream`?

Comment: the extension ( ShowItemMessageStream ) is just a trait which forces the addItemToMessageStream method to be implemented

Comment: `item` is defined for and instance of `ShowItemMessageStreamMock`. AFAIK `object ShowItemMessageStreamMock` is not an instance of `ShowItemMessageStreamMock`.

Comment: ok first of all thank you:), but I always thought, that the values are shared between the object and the class, so that theres no problem with accessing the value in the object?

Comment: Values are not shared, they are either in an instance or in the companion object. Values in the companion object can be accessed by all instances, but they have to be declared inside the companion object.

Comment: @helloworld. Imagine if you have created 1000 instances of `ShowItemMessageStreamMock`. Which one's `item` would be accessed by `ShowItemMessageStreamMock.item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, why can´t I acces this item value?

Because it doesn't exist. The companion object `ShowItemMessageStreamMock` does not have an `item` member.

You could put the assertion inside the `case class` like this:

```
case class ShowItemMessageStreamMock[A](item: A) {
   assert(item.nonEmpty)
}
```

Of course this won't work because `item` is of unknown type and may not have a `nonEmpty` method, but at least you are checking the right value! And there are better ways of enforcing this than using an assertion.

But the following code is also messed up because it creates an object and then discards all references to it:

```
def addItemToMessageStream[A](view: A): Unit =
{
    new ShowItemMessageStreamMock(view)
}
```

It's probably worth taking a step back and explaining what it is you are actually trying to do.